# How to add a variance column with the N previous months

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax, calculated-columns

I have a calculated history of totals table, in which I've put a column with a difference of the total with the previous month (variance?)

[image: table]

The expression is:

```
items_facturation_history_totals_diff = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        items_facturation_history_totals,
            "Diferencia", CALCULATE(SUM(items_facturation_history_totals[Precio Total])) - CALCULATE(SUM(items_facturation_history_totals[Precio Total]), PREVIOUSMONTH(items_facturation_join[fecha]))
        )
    )
```

In this expression I was using the method PREVIOUSMONTH, but now I need to add another column with a variance of the last 3 months, and the last year (12 months) but I don't know how to achieve this.

Any advice?